# Password strength test in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am writing a program for my JS class and I have the code written just a few problems I am not understanding.

```
let readlineSync = require('readline-sync')

let userPassword = readlineSync.question('Please enter a password ')

const testPassword = (password, rulesRegexp, rulesText) => {
    for (let i in rulesRegexp) {
        console.log(rulesText[i]);
        console.log(`Status:  ${rulesRegexp[i].rule.test(password)}`);
    }
};

const rules = [
    { rule: /[A-Z]/ },
    { rule: /[a-z]/ },
    { rule: /[0-9]/ },
    { rule: /[@#$%^]/ },
    { rule: /.{8,}/g },
];

const ruleText = [
    "One or more uppercase letters",
    "One or more lower case letters",
    "One or more numbers",
    "One or more from this group @#$%^",
    "Minimum length 8 characters",
];

testPassword(userPassword, rules, ruleText);
```

I need the rule and test to be on same line and I need it to say passed or failed instead of true or false. I someone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

They're on different lines because that's how logging to the console works. For the passed/failed, check if the `test` method is true/false and change the output with a ternary.

You can push to an array and log like so:

```
const testPassword = (password, rulesRegexp, rulesText) => {
    const results = []
    for (let i in rulesRegexp) {
        const result = `${rulesText[i]} Status:  ${rulesRegexp[i].rule.test(password) ? 'Passed' : 'Failed'}`
        results.push(result)
    }

    console.log(results.join('\n'))
};
```

Sample output:

```
One or more uppercase letters Status:  Failed
One or more lower case letters Status:  Passed
One or more numbers Status:  Passed
One or more from this group @#$%^ Status:  Failed
Minimum length 8 characters Status:  Passed
```

Comment: that worked thank you is there a way I can make passed green and failed red?